# Programmer for Sanyo LC87F5NC8A Microcontroller

Tags: programmer, isp

I want to hack my Samsung DVD player. But the IC used it a Sanyo LC87F5NC8A. I don't have a programmer that can dump or program this UC. Any advice ??

Answer (score 3):

The datasheet is available via Google. Page 4 has lists part numbers for Flash ROM programmers that can program the chip.

Here's one company that makes them: http://www.j-fsg.co.jp/en/index.html

They don't appear to sell the exact models listed in the datasheet, but the AF9709C looks like it might do the job. I bet it's expensive, but you might be able to find out how it operates it, and then emulate it with something cheaper.

Comment: Datasheet comes up very easily on a google search. That invalidates the main reason behind your answer.

Comment: Ah, that does indeed suggest that I am wrong.

Comment: Answer amended.

Comment: Do I get any rep for that?

Comment: Sorry, mjh2007, I didn't even notice your answer when I amended mine. I was just responding to davr's comment above. But I'll upvote you all the same.

Comment: @mjh2007: Hey, how about this-- since you came up with the Google result before me, why don't you take the last two paragraphs of my answer and add it to yours, and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

The programming algorithm should be in the documentation for the chip. You could implement it on another MCU.

Answer (score 2):

I found the datasheet by doing a Google search for the part online. In the datasheet it references a number of different programmers to use with that chip.

Answer (score 0):

You could buy a different DVD player which somebody else has already hacked/reverse engineered. In terms of effort and time, that's going to be a lot easier.